# Autenticação basica no Gradle do Android [iniciante]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy, android-gradle

Sou Estagiario. Tenho um projeto android, estou em build.gradle, meu superior disse que para fins de segurança eu não poderia editar o projeto (codigo-fonte) para inserir minha autenticação, que eu deveria achar um jeito pelo Gradle em utilizar estas variaveis ${nomUser}, rodar na minha maquina.

Nós utilizamos o Nexus (Sonotype) a qual o link https://libs.mycompany.com.br/repository/mycompany-app-release/ vai consultar para autenticação, se eu pudesse editar eu conseguiria, mas não sei como posso fazer isso pelo gradle sem editar codigo fonte, suspeito que devo fazer um script, mas não tenho certeza.

Só utilizando
username = "${nomUser}"
password = "${nomPassword}, dá erro de "Could not get unknown property 'nomUser' for credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredential

Assisti mais de 15 videos na internet atentamente sobre o que é o Gradle, como funciona, mas nenhum tratou de credentials, na documentação não consegui ver algo direto ao meu problema, tive alguns insights como procurar settings.gradle na pasta C://gradle, mas descartei porque nem existia isso lá, logo percebi que isso é longe da realidade, estou começando a programar agora.

```
allprojects {
      repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
         maven {
               credentials {
                          username = "${nomUser}"
                          password = "${nomPassword}"
                          }
               url 'https://libs.mycompany.com.br/repository/mycompany-app-release/'
               authentication {
                    basic(BasicAuthentication)
               }}
         maven { url 'http://sales.mycompany.github.io/AAAA-SDK-Android/repository' }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ja resolvi com "gradlew publish -PnomUser=***** -PnomPassword=******"
O video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvXjlxJg2II me ajudou bastante